# How to use ansible to assign multiple existing users to a new group

Tags: linux, ansible, automation, ansible-playbook

I created a new group in OS. Now I want to assign 5 or more existing users to that group using ansible. I believe I could do this for single user.

```
---
- name: add user to a group
  become: 'yes'
  become_method: sudo
  hosts: all

  tasks:

  - user:
        name: myusername
        groups: new_group
        append: yes
...
```

I want to assign all users to that group in one go instead of running the script several time with different username each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to explore `with_items`.

From the top of my head, it should look like this:

```
- user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: my_group
    append: yes
  with_items:
    - johnsmith
    - beckyjones
    - foobar
```

You can, of course create a separate list of users in a variable, and call `with_items: "{{ userlist }}"`.

Note the indentation: `with_items` is in the same indentation level as the module name you call.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!